# Make Stored Procedure parameters cascading in Crystal Reports

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I don't have a lot of experience using Stored Procedure as a data source for Crystal Reports. My question is that when you connect to an Oracle Stored procedure which has 2 parameters - Country and City, the parameters are already mapped in Crystal individually. Is there a way i can make these parameters cascading i.e. Country > City, either on front end or backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add a stored procedure to the report, you should see the two parameters listed in the Parameter Fields section in the Field Explorer.

Edit one of the parameters, select 'Dynamic' from the List of Values picklist.  Click the first row below in the Value column to select which field in your SP will contain the value (key) for Country.  Do the same for the description.  Click the second row to follow the same process for the City.

The parameters' values will be limited to what the SP returns.

If you publish the report to BusinessObjects Enterprise, it will create a BusinessView (and lots of other objects) to host the List of Values.  This allows you to specify a broader (not just limited to the SP's result) set of values.