# In Crystal Reports XI, can I populate stored two procedure parameters from a dynamic cascading parameter?

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, crystal-reports

I'm building a report using Crystal Reports XI that calls a SQL Server stored procedure that expects parameters @Type_ID and @Subtype_ID.

There's also a table in the database that associates Types and Subtypes in a one-to-many relationship.

I'd like to have the report's parameters prompt screen ask for:

- Type - either one of the listed Types or Null. If Null, the screen won't ask for a Subtype.
- Subtype - either one of the listed Subtypes that's associated with the selected Type or Null.

... and pass these two values to the stored procedure as @Type_ID and @Subtype_ID, respectively. (If the stored procedure gets @Type_ID = Null, it will return records of all types. If it gets @Type_ID <> Null and @Subtype_ID = Null, it will return records of all subtypes associated with the selected type.)

**Is there a way to make my Crystal report do all this?**

So far, using advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197014/179), I set up a dynamic cascading parameter (DCP) on @Subtype_ID, which asks for a Type and then a Subtype in the way I describe above, then passes the selected Subtype to @Subtype_ID. However, I haven't yet figured out how to pass the Type selected through this DCP to @Type_ID, so that if Subtype is Null, the stored procedure can return all records with the selected Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your procedure's definition creates to two parameters: `TYPE_ID` and `SUBTYPE_ID`.  Crystal Reports' parameters (dynamic or static) weren't designed to interact with each other.

As I see it, you have three options:

- create a report w/ the *single* prompt group (make sure that the prompt group creates two parameters) that you want (the main report doesn't require a data source, btw); insert a subreport that uses your procedure (it will create two parameters); link the parameters in the main report to parameters in the subreport; if necessary, you can create formulae in the main report (which are then linked to the two parameters in the subreport) for extra logic (convert a parameter value of 'All Type Id' to NULL, for example).
- refactor your procedure to have a single `VARCHAR` parameter that will receive a concatenated `TYPE_ID` and `SUBTYPE_ID`.  Create a dynamic parameter that will have a concatenated value for the key and for the description (e.g. 1/3; Type [1] - Subtype [3]).  Your procedure's logic will need to parse the parameter's value to determine the values of `TYPE_ID` and `SUBTYPE_ID`.  You'll need to create a query that generates the keys and descriptions, which will be exposed through a BusinessView's various layers.
- abandon the procedure in favor of a Command or 'normal' query.  in my experience, **the vast majority of reports can be build without a stored procedure**.  Combined w/ a single prompt group, this will give you the flexibility that you need.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented something along the lines of your second option.

Comment: I won't; I'm just going to give it another day to see if anyone else answers.